# Low voter turnout

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, up-votes

I only now learned that [rep is required to upvote](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/137436/83790). I came here to confirm that, and found [this related Q&A](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/why-doesnt-anyone-vote-on-this-site). The statistics are interesting. And given that the majority of questions on any given day is from users with `rep=1`, that could have a knock-on effect.

Not suggesting changes... just ["thinking out loud"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thinking+out+loud).

Comment: For reference, the [vote up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) privilege is granted when a user has earned 15 reputation.

Comment: Indeed. I'm a [Community Manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369260/335251) (on the [Community Engagement & Enablement team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/335251)) at Stack Exchange, Inc.

Comment: @V2Blast: Well good for you. I don't recall interacting with `Staff` previously, but it's good to know that "corporate" is keeping an eye on things. As long as you're here, perhaps you'd be interested in [another question I've asked recently](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2332/serial-voting-penalty)? You needn't comment if you prefer, but I would like to bring this to the attention of someone who might be able to improve things. And please know this: my criticism is *pointed*, but not intended to be *personal*.